# ListView in Windows 7 style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using Windows 10 and my ListView looks like Windows 7:

[image: 1]

It should looks like that:

[image: 2]

Buttons look normal.[image: 3]]

How to fix it?

```
<ListView Name="projectsList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="176" Margin="10,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Project Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProjectName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Create Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreateTime}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think MS updated the default control template of ListView's or ListBox's to the Windows 10 style. You'll just have to manually style it - most likely by overriding the controltemplate for the control and setting the properties to emulate the OS style.

Comment: That screenshot is not actually a ListView.  Microsoft no longer shares their controls, everybody is today expected to style it their own way.  By popular demand.  And the common controls are end-of-life, UWP is the today's widget provider.  If you want to compare to what it should look like then try a ListView in a Winforms app.